# I'm loading kml with cesium and I want to add a border to kml

Tags: javascript

## **loading kml with cesium**

I'm loading kml with cesium and I want to add a border to kml

**I use the attributes cesium uses to try to add**

```
  var canvas = viewer.dataSources.add(Cesium.KmlDataSource.load('./assets/doc.kml', {
                 camera: viewer.scene.camera,
                 canvas: viewer.scene.canvas
             }));
```

## add a border to kml

```
 canvas.then(function (dataSource) {
                viewer.dataSources.add(dataSource);
                viewer.clock.shouldAnimate = false;
                var entities = dataSource.entities.values;                    
                 for (var i = 0; i < entities.length; i++) {
                 var entity = entities[i];
                 entity.polygon.outline = true; 
                 console.log(entity.polygon.outline)
                 entity.polygon.outlineColor = Cesium.Color.BLACK;
                }
```

Comment: And what's your question about this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.